# Tag for calculating way length in osm2pgsql?

Tags: openstreetmap, database, osm2pgsql, length

There is a special tag `'way_area'` in osm2pgsql creating a database column that stores the area of polygon features. So is there something like this for calculation of length of line objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but use can use PostGIS function `ST_Length` for that. It returns length in meters if `way` field is of geography type. That is, to get length in meters, convert it: `ST_Length(ST_Transform(way, 4326)::geography)`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you just want to order by length, ST_Length(way) will work if only considering a reasonable sized area as once, assuming you have imported with a conformal projection like Web Mercator